# How to extend the set of APIs visible to the logexts extension of windbg/cdb/ntdb?

Tags: debugging, com, certificate, windbg, trace

I trace certutil using the following cdb script (named TraceScript.txt):

```
!logexts.loge c:\logs
!logexts.logc e *
!logexts.logo d d
!logexts.logo d t
!logexts.logo e v
g
!logexts.logb f
q
```

and the following batch file (named trace.cmd):

```
@echo off
set SYMBOL_PATH=srv*c:\users\markk\appdata\local\temp\symbolcache
cdb -y %SYMBOL_PATH% -cf c:\utils\TraceScript.txt %*
```

All is fine, but I have noticed the following line in the output:

```
[LogHookComInterface] Interface {7a18edde-7e78-4163-8ded-78e2c9cee924} is unknown -- not logging.
```

Where the GUID corresponds to the following registry path:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{7A18EDDE-7E78-4163-8DED-78E2C9CEE924}
```

Which in turn corresponds to the `ICertConfig2` interface - seems relevant, isn't it?

Anyway, I am wondering whether it is possible to make this interface visible to the logger, because without it all the logging is useless. How do I know it? The logger reports a single invocation of the CoCreateInstance API with the GUID 372FCE38-4324-11D0-8810-00A0C903B83C, which corresponds to the CertConfig class, which I guess implements the ICertConfig2 interface. No other certificate related APIs appear in the log. So without the ICertConfig2 interface the log is useless.

Any ideas?

*P.S.*

I will gladly accept ways to trace the ICertConfig2 COM API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the files under (path to windbg)\winext\manifest

The files there contain the definitions used by the logger extension.  com.h contain definitions for interfaces

uuid.h contain the mapping from GUID to interfaces.

you will need to convert the definition of ICertConfig2 to the format used by the tool

Comment: Let me get it straight. I modify the two .h files and that is it? Without recompiling anything? I am a bit skeptical. Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Yes, just modify the two files.  Both the logviewer and the logger parse the manifest files every time.   I've used this myself with other APIs.

Comment: Do you happen to know where can I get the manifests for some SDK headers? Creating them manually is hell of a lot of work...

Comment: I give up. Seems like tons of APIs missing from the manifest and adding them manually is just not how I envision my next 20 years.